# Another relative Künneth formula

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

The Künneth formula for relative (co)homology as stated e.g. in [Hatcher](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/ATpage.html) says that
$$ H^n(X\times Y,A\times Y\cup X\times B;R)\cong \bigoplus_{i} H^i(X,A;R)\otimes_R H^{n-i}(Y,B;R),$$
if $H^{i}(Y,B;R)$ is a finitely generated free $R$-module for each $i$.

Is there a Künneth-type formula for $H^n(X,A\times B;R)$, assuming that $(X,A\times B)$ is a good pair?

Comment: How could $A\times B$ be a subspace of $X$?